# Steam Controller

Tags: microcontroller, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
There is some way to use the [Steam Controller](http://store.steampowered.com/app/353370/Steam_Controller/) like the XBOX or PS3?
Thank you...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276937/steam-controller/) by [synapsido](https://answers.ros.org/users/20161/synapsido/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2017-11-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of any packages for this, but a quick Google returned [this gist](https://gist.github.com/awesomebytes/d9dad21ba07eed27adb8) by @awesomebytes that shows how to interface with it (the IMU in this case, but principle should be the same).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1